# Will the capacitor stop receiving more voltage when max is reached

Tags: voltage, capacitor

I'm trying to understand how capacitors acts in different situations.

Let say i have a constant power input source that is rated 5v and my capacitor that is 100uf 25v is receiving this voltage.

If the power input is always running and the capacitor is keep receiving it without without passing it over to any component. will the capacitor keep storing the voltage until it reach 25v and fail/explode if it exceed that limit or will it just stop accepting more until the power have been used ?

Comment: By what mechanism do you think that the capacitor would end up with a higher voltage than that applied?   25v is a *rating* ie, a limit above which dielectric failure could occur.

Comment: Is it a constant *power* source, or is it a constant *voltage* source rated at 5V, such as a USB charger?

Comment: @Chris Stratton i don't quite understand in case the capacitor never release anything, but keep getting 5v

Comment: @TimWescott  it a constant voltage source rated at 5V from a regulator

Comment: @John that seems to be a misunderstanding of what "voltage" is

Comment: @ChrisStratton my apologies i meant volts

Comment: That is not a meaningful difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitor can only charge up to the applied voltage, regardless of the capacitor's voltage rating.

The voltage rating of a capacitor is the maximum voltage that it can withstand without damage.

If you connect a 5 volt source to a capacitor rated at 25 volts, current will only flow into the capacitor until it is charged to 5 volts.

Comment: Just to confirm. So even if you never use the energy inside the capacitor and the 5 volt source ( from  regulator ) is still connected to the capacitor, it will not damage the capacitor or overcharge?

Comment: That's right.  You might want to look into the difference between potential difference (measured in volts) and current (measured in amps).  When there's a difference between the potential stored in the capacitor (as charge, measured in coulombs, divided by its capacity, measured in farads) and the potential applied, a current flows.  It is this current that charges or discharges the capacitor.

Comment: @Chromatix Great thank you for confirm that !

Comment: It is perfectly normal (and even essential) to connect capacitors between a power supply bus and Ground.  These power supply bypass or filter capacitors do not "overcharge" or get damaged, although they are exposed to a constant voltage all the time the circuit is powered.  In Real Life, there will be some current flowing in and out of the bypass and filter capacitors as they attempt to hold the supply voltage constant.

Comment: @PeterBennett i'm so grateful for your help and explanation, thank you very much!